# Thymeleaf + Javascript select option change

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf, jquery-select2

I want to select a list of elements, based on selection I call a function api that give me with a list of data, to insert in a second selection.

The call works fine, I try to alert the result, but I need to change the value of second selection and I fail.
I'm using **select2**.

This is my **THYMELEAF** page:

```
   <form id="updateD" data-parsley-validate class="rounded px-2 py-2 mt-3" th:action="@{/ditta/upd}" th:method="POST" th:object="${ditta}">

<div class="row" th:if="*{codice==null or codice.isEmpty()}">
                    <div th:replace="~{/tags/input :: inputNorm(indirizzo, *{indirizzo}, text, true, '')}"></div>
                    <div th:replace="~{/tags/select :: selectValue(city, *{city}, ${cities}, false)}"></div>
                    <div th:replace="~{/tags/select :: selectValue(zip, *{zipCode}, ${zips}, false)}"></div>
                </div>
</form>
```

JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
        var token = $('#_csrf').attr('content');
        var header = $('#_csrf_header').attr('content');

        $(function(){

            $('#city').change(function(){
                handleComune($('#city').val());
            });

            $('.sel2').select2({
                theme: "bootstrap"
            });
        });

        function handleComune(city){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                 url:[[ @{'/api/extractZip?city='}]]+city,
                 beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                   xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
               },
               success : function(data) {
                   $('#zips').val(data);
                   alert(data);
               }
            });
        }

    /*]]>*/
    </script>
```

Based on the choice of the city I extract a zipcode list.

The **fragments** of the select is the follow:

```
    <div th:fragment="selectValue(name, selected, values, required)" class="col form-group" th:switch="${required}">

        <label th:text="${required} ? #{${name}}+'*' : #{${name}}" th:for="${name}" class="control-label"></label>

<div class="col form-group">
            <select th:name="${name}" th:id="${name}" class="form-control sel2" th:required="${required}">
                <option value=""></option>
                <th:block th:each="v : ${values}">
                    <option th:value="${v}" th:text="${v}" th:selected="${selected} eq ${v}"></option>
                </th:block>
            </select>
        </div>

    </div>
```

The  **$('#zips').val(data);**  not change.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you are returning a Thymeleaf fragment from your Controller, then you will be getting a html code. So, `val()` won't work. You need to use `append(data)`. Now I don't see your Controller or where the element `$('#zips')` is at, so I am assuming that is what you are sending.

If you are sending a list of entities, then you would need to use `$.each(data, function() { // Do something });` to add each entity as an option in your select.

Comment: Hi Alain, I solved after an intense afternoon spent trying, trying and trying again. Your answer is partially correct. I solved using this code: ` success : function(data) {
                    $('#zip').empty();
                    var arrayCap = data.toString().split(",");
                    
                    for (a in arrayCap ) {
                     var newOption = new Option(data[a], data[a], false, false);
                     $('#zip').append(newOption).trigger('change');
                  }
                   }`

Answer (score 1):

After several attempts I solved this way:

```
 function handleComune(city){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                 url:[[ @{'/api/extractZip?city='}]]+city,
                 beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                   xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
               },
               success : function(data) {
                   $('#zip').empty();
                       var arrayCap = data.toString().split(",");

                       for (a in arrayCap ) {
                           var newOption = new Option(data[a], data[a], false, false);
                           $('#zip').append(newOption).trigger('change');
                        }
               }
            });
        }
```

I need to split my data, because the response is string of data separated by commas.

Now it works perfectly!